# Flask- Not able to get PUT method working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

Having trouble trying to get PUT method to work. Every time I try

`curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/videos/video3 -d "title=YES" -X PUT` in the terminal, I end up with an error that says: `{"message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."}`

I've tried the code below and was able to get the GET method working and thought I was getting close with PUT method but now got stuck.

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse, abort

app = Flask("VideoAPI")
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser() 
parser.add_argument('title',required=True)

videos = {
    'video1': {'title': 'Hello World in Python'},
    'video2': {'title': 'Why Matlab is the Best Language Ever'}
}


class Video(Resource):
    def get(self, video_id):
        if video_id == "all":
            return videos 
        if video_id not in videos:
            abort(404, message=f"Video {video_id} not found")
        return videos[video_id]
    
    
    def put(self, video_id):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        new_video = {'title': args['title']}
        videos[video_id] = new_video
        return {video_id: videos[video_id]}, 201
    
api.add_resource(Video, '/videos/<video_id>')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Expected Output: `{"video1": {"title": "Hello World In Python"}, "video2": {"title": Why Matlab is the best language ever"}, "video3": {"title": "YES"}}`

Comment: What output do you see in the running server when making the request?

Comment: Did you make sure to restart the server before testing the put call?

Comment: Hello, and I ended up restarting the server multiple times. This is what I'm getting when I insert the call "127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2023 19:22:24] "PUT /videos/video3 HTTP/1.1" 400 -"

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify the Content-Type header in the request, `curl` sends it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. Therefore, if you add `location='form'` to the argument definition it should work correctly:

```
parser.add_argument('title', required=True, location='form')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your put method is expecting a JSON format `{"title": "YES"}` but the data you sent was not that format.

Curl request should be

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"title": "YES"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/videos/video3
```

Response

```
{
    "video3": {
        "title": "YES"
    }
}
```

To get your expected output

```
def put(self, video_id):
    args = parser.parse_args()
    new_video = {'title': args['title']}
    videos[video_id] = new_video
    # return {video_id: videos[video_id]}, 201
    return videos, 201
```